# Unable to remove the www from url on https using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to remove www from my site url.

ie. https://www.domainname.com.au to https://domainname.com.au.

I have tried it various .htacces code but nothing work for me.

Here is my present code which remove www from http but not work for https.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainname.com.au/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^code-of-conducts/(.*)/$ code-of-conducts.php?type=$1 
RewriteRule ^parents/post-a-job/(.*)/EDIT/$ parents/post-a-job.php?action=EDIT&id=$1 
RewriteRule ^parents/post-a-job/(.*)/$ parents/post-a-job.php?job_type=$1 
RewriteRule ^parents/open-jobs/(.*)/delete/$ parents/open-jobs.php?action=delete&id=$1 
RewriteRule ^parent-profile/(.*)/$ parent-profile.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule ^parents/job-details/(.*)$ parents/job-details.php?applied_id=$1 

RewriteRule ^sitterprofile/(.*)/$ sitterprofile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^sitter/job-board/state/(.*)/page/(.*)/$ sitter/job-board.php?state=$1&in_page=$2 
RewriteRule ^sitter/job-board/state/(.*)/$ sitter/job-board.php?state=$1 
RewriteRule ^sitter/job-details/(.*)$ sitter/job-details.php?applied_id=$1 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  $1.php 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Try adding this also.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added your code in my .htaccess file. But not work for me. @dexa

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first `www` removal code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```